# Avoid to make this culture check every call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, session, .net-4.0

Let me give you some background on my scenario. I got a multi language site and my cultures are stored in database and got a property that is `public bool Active { get; set; }`

1. If you come to my site with lets say a Russian culture on your browser, that is not supported on my site so i need to set the culture to "se" (or whatever).
2. If you come to my site with a supported culture but its not Active i need to set it to a default one "se" (or whatever).

Now I can do this check easy in my `override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler` method. The thing is I dont want to make the call to the database everytime the site makes any call on the site. My thought is that I do a session["firstVisit"] to reduce that check but I kinda don't know how i should go about to that, because my scenario it say that 
**`not set to an instance of an object`** on the session["firstVisit"] line, so my question is how do I handle this? And what other options I got to go about this?

my thought is something like this

```
protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {            
            String culture = requestContext.RouteData.Values["culture"].ToString();

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["firstVisit"].ToString() == string.Empty)
            {
                //do the check
            }

            var ci = new CultureInfo(culture);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
            return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
        }
```

**EDIT** 
Doh why did I not think of that, I ended up just doing a check in the `protected void Application_Start()` to avoid sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Session_Start( object sender, EventArgs e )
```

This method is called when the session is first created.  You can do the check then, stuff your language info in the session and have it for as long as the session is live through the user's interaction with your site.

Comment: thanks got me on the right track, dont know why i did not think of using the Application_Start()

Comment: Application start is likely NOT what you want.  That's only called once when the entire application is started.  It sounded like you wanted to check when the user first contacted your site (which is session_start).

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood.  You want to cache all your languages to speed lookup.  Application_Start it is then :)